# Calculate mean of numpy array section without for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array:

`a.shape:`
`(24, 124, 117, 1)`

If I take a 10 x 10 subset of the two internal arrays

```
b = a[:,34:44,100:110,0]
```

`b.shape:`

```
(24, 10, 10)
```

To get a list of the mean of the value in each 10 x 10 array:

```
the_list = []
for i in b:
    the_list.append(np.nanmean(i))

print(the_list)
[1.3890099800025781, 1.4469500441974863, 1.3629133841057566, 1.415756533959169, 1.4254133193054614, 1.5217992758345105, 1.6735920775699795, 1.968677630129286, 2.097451850128511, 2.1386300417406416, 2.536669441756218, 2.3351648894197727, 2.794611866191022, 2.524879009293537, 3.1834270587157953, 4.049452682004729, 3.1542556793742387, 3.498059377421739, 4.439820758482223, 3.446379020262416, 4.8295208426437535, 3.7539767849251833, 5.08349934334655, 4.448043719645083]
```

What is a better way to do this instead of `for` loop?

Comment: Just use `numpy.nanmean` on intended axis.

Comment: Is it a sliding window that you are working with? Are you using `nanmean` because it would have NaNs?

Comment: Yes I have NaNs, masked sections.

Comment: So np.nanmean(a[:,34:44,100:110,0])? - This just gives a mean of everything.

Comment: `np.nanmean(a[:,34:44,100:110,0], axis=(-1, -2)`

Comment: That's it Nils. Add answer and I will tick.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.nanmean(a[:,34:44,100:110,0], axis=(-1, -2)
```

Thanks to Nils in comments.